# How to put a point on an elliptic curve using javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, point, private-key, elliptic-curve

So i m trying to send a message from server to client and i m trying to put that message on the elliptic curve as a point and then make the addition of that point to itself K times ! i couldn't find a library in javascript that make the addition of one point to itself !so i m trying to find some solutions in javascript please !

```
i need library in javascript thats can :

-put a "message" on the elliptic curve as a point
-make the addition of two points(or the addition of the same point to itself) on the elliptic curve to get another Point P+P=Q
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto

Comment: @Bergi thank u for your answer but the link doesn t talk about elliptic curve cryptography